# Has already vs had already

Tags: word-usage

Can someone please explain the difference between 'has already' and 'had already'?

Comment: May I suggest you visit our sister site - English Language Learners.

Comment: Also have a look at this question: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21846/how-do-the-tenses-and-aspects-in-english-correspond-temporally-to-one-another

Answer (score 1):

Minnow has directed you to an excellent answer with an excellent diagram that illustrates what portions of the timeline the various English verb forms cover.  There you'll find that the auxiliary *has*/*have* signals present perfect (completed action from an indeterminate time in the past all the way up to just about now), and the auxiliary *had* signals past perfect (completed action from an indeterminate time in the past prior to a fixed time in the past).  Note how the tense of the verb affects the meaning of *already*.

Consider the present perfect with the verb "to leave":  *has* already *left*:

> A: Will you see Katy tonight?
>  B: No, she *has* already *left* town.

Katy left at some time in the past, not specified.  *Already* means that she departed up to *this* time, i.e., her departure preceded the present.

Now consider the past perfect: *had* already *left*:

> A: Will you see Karty tonight?
>  B: No, she *had* already *left*
>   before I got here.

Katy left at some time the past and her departure preceded a fixed past time, namely my arrival.  Here *already* means that she departed up to *that* time, i.e., her departure preceded the fixed time in the past at which I arrived.